# NSDictionary allKeysForObject in an array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a NSDictonary that looks like this. I need to get all the key values that are associated for a particular name. For example the name Samrin is associated with keys 11.titleKey, 110.titleKey and so on. The problem I have is that I am not sure how can I get to the object in an array and then pass they key value back?

I tried the following code with not much success.

[image]

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *stringsPlistPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"birthdays.plist"];
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:stringsPlistPath];

    NSArray *temp = [dictionary allKeysForObject:@"Samrin Ateequi"];
    NSLog(@"temp: %@ ...", temp);

OUTPUT: 
temp: (
) ...
```

Comment: Have you tried just writing the obvious algorithm, using a loop?

Comment: temp is returned as an empty array?

Comment: is the plist loaded correctly? have you tried just logging the dictionary out and see if the object is actually in there?

Comment: @HotLicks loop is going to get ugly for me as I may need to get allKeysForObject for multiple names and looping each one 790+ times is not efficient

Comment: Unfortunately, with the current data structure looping over everything is the only option. If you need to run this multiple times and efficiency is a concern, you should build a new dictionary that uses the names as keys and arrays of associated titles as the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `keysOfEntriesPassingTest` for that. Something like:

```
NSSet *keysSet = [dictionary keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
                 if ([[obj objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"Samrin Ateequi"]) {
                     return YES;
                 } else {
                     return NO;
                 }
}];
```

Comment: that was perfect, simple, easy and elegant. Thank you!

Comment: That, of course, loops over everything.  It just hides the loop.

Comment: @SamBudda glad you found it useful :)

Comment: @HotLicks you're right, essentially it's the same thing, just a bit more elegant imo

Comment: @HotLicks I timed my action of looping over the dic using for loop and the above solution and for some reason for loop was slower. Not sure why?

Comment: @SamBudda - There probably is some savings from being able to access the data using internal interfaces.  But it would not change the "big O" efficiency.  There's no free lunch.  Major improvements would require re-thinking the problem.

Comment: @spassas  Correct me if i am wrong,  It will not going to work if @"Samrin Ateequi" is not at 0th index of array of a corresponding key. See my solution for at any index.

Answer (score 0):

`allKeysForObject:` looks through the dictionary for values equal to that object using `isEqual:`. Your values for that dictionary are NSArrays, so it will never match the NSString you are looking for.

If you don't change the data structure you will have to loop through everything to get the results you need.

If you are willing to upgrade to Core Data with an SQL store, then your results will be fast and the code will be easier than looping through the dictionary. This is the kind of problem that Core Data was meant to solve. You can get started with the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Hope this will help you: I have taken an example.

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"key1":@[@"mania",@"champ"],
                       @"key2":@[@"mann",@"champ"],
                       @"key3":@[@"mania",@"champ",@"temp"]};


NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF=%@",@"mania"];
NSArray *allValues = [dict allValues];
NSArray *requiredRows = [allValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];

NSMutableArray *requiredKeyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:0];

for (id anObj in requiredRows) {
    [requiredKeyArray addObject:[dict allKeysForObject:anObj]];
}
 NSLog(@"Desc: %@",[requiredKeyArray description]);
```